# export html table to excel Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, exceljs

I have an object like this:

```
obj = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [0, 0,0], 'c': [1, 0, 4]}
```

I display it in a html table like this:

```
Code | sum1 | sum2 | sum 3
a    | 1    |  2   | 3
b    | 0    |  0   | 0
c    | 1    |  0   | 4
```

And I want to export this table into excel. This is my code:

```
export() {
    let w = new Workbook();
    let ws = w.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
    ws.addRow(['Code', 'sum1', 'sum2', 'sum3'])
    for (let i = 0; i < this.obj['a'].length; i++) {
      ws.addRow(['a', this.obj['a'][i]])
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.obj['a'].length; i++) {
      ws.addRow(['b', this.obj['b'][i]])
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.obj['a'].length; i++) {
      ws.addRow(['c', this.obj['c'][i]])
    }
}
```

but this won't add the objects on rows, but on columns(something like this:)

```
Code | sum1 | sum2 | sum3
a    | 1    |      |
a    | 2    |      | 
a    | 3    |      |
b    | 0    |      |
b    | 0    |      |
b    | 0    |      |
c    | 1    |      |
c    | 0    |      |
c    | 4    |      |
```

How can I solve this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would try just `ws.addRow(this.obj['a'])` without iterating the inner elements.

Comment: This won't work, because the whole array `[1, 2, 3]` for example, will be added inside `a:sum1` cell

Comment: import { Workbook } from 'exceljs'

Comment: I am surprised it would add the whole array to sum1 but, also, how does it currently put a,b,c into the Code column? Anyway, because there are four columns but three values, I would first put the letter 'a' ('b' then 'c') into the array using unshift before attempting again with my suggestion above.

Comment: Sorry, I've made some mistakes while writing the code above. Check the edit, please.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what you say. Can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate all of the inner array elements, that is why it creates many rows.

Consider that `addRow` will add a single row each time, so you need to ensure that the array you will add has the same number of columns as the array `['Code', 'sum1', 'sum2', 'sum3']`. Use `unshift` to insert the key ('a', 'b', 'c') at the front of each respective array.

```
this.obj['a'].unshift('a');
ws.addRow(this.obj['a']);
```

Do the same for 'b' and 'c'.

You could also unpack 'a' and its elements to a new array if you do not wish to modify the original.

(It would also be possible to iterate the obj keys rather than repeating the above lines three times.)

---

Iterating the keys to unshift could look like this:

```
let k;
for (k of Object.keys(this.obj)) {

    this.obj[k].unshift(k);
    ws.addRow(this.obj[k]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand!

Comment: I tried to create a copy of `obj` and shift on it, but the table inside html shifts. It's like the shift is still made on `obj`, not on a copy of it. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Not without seeing code. You should probably start a new question for this.